# Proper way of re-using and passing multiple queries in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

My website has `Object` as the model and `ObjectSearch` as the searchModel. I realized that I am already having a lot of duplicates in my two different controllers. For example, `FirstController` has this:

```
$arr = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT id, name, address
        FROM hosts)->queryAll();
```

Then at some part of my website `SecondController` also needs to use that same query.

How can I re-use that query over and over again from different controllers?

I am talking about this:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Host::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        ]
    ]);
    .
    .
    .
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

I have another question also. I am planning to do different queries. What is the best approach for making another query? Should I use that

`public function search($params)`

again and maybe add on the parameter like this?

```
public function search($params, $cond)
{

    if ($cond == true) {
         $query = *something;
    }

    else {
         $query = *something_else;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify where the code samples are? Are they in your controller, or your model, and which model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root folder, you are having **component folder**. Inside component folder, create one page like **UserInfoComponent.php**. This page will be common and can be use anywhere.

This is the **Directory Structure**

```
YourProjectFolder
    ->assets
    ->commands
    ->components
        ->UserInfoComponent.php
    .
    .
```

**UserInfoComponent.php**

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;

class UserInfoComponent extends Component 
{
    .
    .
    public function getUserDetails() {
        $arr = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT id, name, address FROM hosts')->queryAll();
        return $arr;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now, how to call this function in your controller or view.

**Controller** or **view**

```
<?
$arrValue = Yii::$app->userinfo->getUserDetails(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For common function you can create an helper class

```
namespace myapp\myhelperdir

class MyQueryHelper
{


   public static function mySelectFunction ($param)
   {
        // your code for function
        return $yourResult;

   }
```

then you can refer to these function in every part of your project simply adding

```
use myapp\myhelperdir\MyQueryHelper

$myResult = MyQueryHelper::mySelectFunction($myParam);
```